# `require` child namespace :as shorthand in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

Suppose we have a project with namespaces: `proj.foo`, `proj.bar`, `proj.baz`.  Since we are inside the context of `proj`, we want access to `foo/foo` *unprefixed*, instead of `proj.foo/foo`.  You can do this with `ns` but it's verbose:

```
(ns proj.qux
  (:require (proj
              [foo :as foo]
              [bar :as bar]
              [baz :as baz])))
```

Is there a shorthand way to accomplish this?  It seems like a common task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can construct the functionality you want using `alias`.

```
(defn common-alias [ns-symbol]
  (alias ((comp symbol
                #(re-find #"[^.]+$" %)
                name)
          ns-symbol)
         ns-symbol))
```

used as so:

```
user> string/join
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: No such namespace: string, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:1:764) 
user> (common-alias 'clojure.string)
nil
user> string/join
#<string$join clojure.string$join@22830870>
```

Answer (score -1):

A couple of options here:

```
(ns proj.qux
  (:require [proj [foo :refer :all] [bar :refer :all]]))
```

This will allow you to use all public vars from `proj.foo` etc. unprefixed, but you must be sure that there're no name clashes w/ symbols in those namespaces.

```
(ns proj)

(load "proj/foo")
(load "proj/bar")
(load "proj/baz")
```

This too allows you to refer to vars defined in those files without prefix, but maybe isn't what you're after: This approach literally includes the three files into the main `proj` ns, however `foo`, `bar`, `baz` technically aren't namespaces as such in this case. You're simply using different **files** to build up a single ns `proj`. Each of those included files should  have **no** `(ns ...)` form and the above example assumes this folder structure (note that you don't specify the `.clj` extension for `(load ...)`):

```
src
|- proj.clj
|- proj
   |- foo.clj
   |- bar.clj
   |- baz.clj
```

Comment: May I ask why this got downvoted? I explained it might not be the thing the OP was after, but then please provide more details/context... thx!

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I don't think this is quite idiomatic.  Also, it puts everything in foo/bar/baz into the *current* namespace--it modifies the current namespace.  The thing I was asking about was to just give them other namespaces shorter namespace names, but still keep them in separate namespaces.